# Launch Failed, LibGDX IOS Device

Tags: ios, libgdx

I have trying to make an ios app out of libgdx. I have an Ipad (no iphone yet) an I am trying to upload my app to the device. I have an XCode 7.2, which means that it guarantees that I can upload an app to an apple device without an Apple Developer Account, which currently I have none. I had successfully uploaded an app onto my Ipad with XCode alone. In Eclipse, a simple test app runs perfectly on an IOS Simulator. But when I tried to run it in an IOS device, it does not work. Since it is just a free provision, I was hoping this would work. The Bundle identifier of the xcode app with free provisioning is the same as the app id and main class of my eclipse ios app. Before this, there was an error that no provision was set, so I set the bundle identifier of the xcode app the same with the eclipse app, according to roboVM(http://docs.robovm.com/getting-started/provisioning.html#free-provisioning). But then this error shows up,

"Launch IOS Device App" has encountered a problem.

Launch failed. Check the RoboVM console for more information.

The given data is not a property list of a supported format.

I need to test my app on a real device because I am going to try to implement an online multiplayer with it. As of now I am still using LibGDX 1.5.5. Is it because roboVM needs an apple developer account?

Edit: Even without any device connected, the error persists

Comment: I know its not a direct answer to your question but why don't you get an apple developer account? You will need it later on anyways.

Comment: I will if it fixes the problem. Its just that right now, my time learning ios development is very limited that having one just isn't worth it at the moment. That's why I'm asking in advance.

Comment: Try this from a terminal: ./gradlew ios:launchIOSDevice --stacktrace . This will give you further information on what the problem might be.

Comment: This is what the error showed https://www.dropbox.com/s/btgvufmexl1gbzt/errorLibgdxIOS.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem as the original poster and it persists in IntelliJ. After some tinkering, it was also showing up on the command line. THanks to some help on the libgdx irc forum, we coudl solve the problem. It was due to running iOS 9.2 on my iOS device and a too old robovm-plugin 1.12.0 seems not to work with libgdx and iOS 9.2. An upgrade to 1.12.1.-SNAPSHOT solved it.

Attention, you have to update two lines in build.gradle:

1. in buildscript - dependencies: classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.12.1-SNAPSHOT'
2. in allprojects - ext: roboVMVersion = '1.12.1-SNAPSHOT'

If you want to compile in IntelliJ, you need to manually install the nightly robovm-plugin from the nightlies download section from the robovm webpage.